# using index to match-up CSS background image with a line-item

Tags: html, css

The following structure generates background images for a collection

```
.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) { background-image: url("1.jpg"); }
.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) { background-image: url("2.jpg"); }
.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) { background-image: url("3.jpg"); }
.accordion ul li:nth-child(4) { background-image: url("4.jpg"); }
```

which is then intended to be laid out as follows

```
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 1</p></a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 2</p></a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This however relies on the premise that the items are in the order of the nth-child generated. The nth child value is being generated by the index of the results of the database query.

However, if one were to generate multiple accordions say

```
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 1</p></a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 2</p></a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 3</p></a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <a href="#"><p>Text 4</p></a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now the divs are just running with the first 2 nth-children background image, as the internal counter is re-set for the div.

How can the index of the nth-child be associated with the relevant line item?

Comment: short answer: you cannot, nth-child() consider only siblings and there is no CSS selector that consider non-sibling elements

Comment: so the only solution is the set up distinct classes for each accordion desired, yes?

Comment: or simply use inline style when generating your code. You can easily track indexes on the backend

Comment: Right.  I think you should outline these 'ways forward' in an answer.

Comment: set the `nth-child()` selector with `.accordion` as well